# Desenhar retangulo vazado usando apenas whiles

Tags: python, while

Tenho um exercício para fazer o computador desenhar um retângulo vazado usando apenas `while`:

```
OOOO
O  O
O  O
OOOO
```

Eu consegui fazer o sólido, porém vazado eu nao tenho nem idéia de como que se faz. E pelo que vi em algumas respostas a uma pergunta parecida as pessoas pegavam valores como altura e largura, armazenavam esses valores em variaveis tipo:

```
Altura = int(input("Digite a altura"))
```

Porém o exercicio me pede que eu pegue apenas uma variável e use esse dado para começar a plotar o retângulo.

O código que consegui fazer do retângulo sólido foi esse aqui:

```
print("PROGRAMA PARA ESCREVER RETANGULOS SOLIDOS NA TELA\n")

digitouDireito = False
while not digitouDireito:
    try:
        qtdLins = int(input ("Deseja um retangulo de quantas linhas de altura? "))

        if qtdLins<0:
            print ("Quantidades devem ser positivas!\n")
        else:
            digitouDireito = True
            qtdCols = qtdLins
    except ValueError:
        print ("Quantidades devem ser numeros naturais!\n")

lin = 1
while lin<=qtdLins:
    col = 1
    while col<=qtdCols:
        print ("O", end="")
        col+=1 #col = col+1
    print()
    lin+=1 # lin = lin+1
    
print ("\nOBRIGADO POR USAR ESTE PROGRAMA!\n")
```

Gostaria de saber o que eu posso fazer nesse codigo para adaptá-lo pro que o exercicio me pede.

Comment: O exemplo que eu queria dar do retangulo usando "O" não saiu muito bem...

Comment: Basta incluir um `if` antes de imprimir: se estiver na primeira ou última linha, ou na primeira ou última coluna, imprime `O`, senão imprime um espaço

Comment: E só pra registrar, em vez de `while`, vc pode fazer assim: https://ideone.com/nxQKO2

Answer (score -1):

Para realizar esta implementação será necessário verificar se a linha é a primeira ou última, ou se a coluna é a primeira ou última, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
print("PROGRAMA PARA ESCREVER RETANGULOS SOLIDOS NA TELA\n")

digitouDireito = False
while not digitouDireito:
    try:
        qtdLins = int(input ("Deseja um retangulo de quantas linhas de altura? "))

        if qtdLins<0:
            print ("Quantidades devem ser positivas!\n")
        else:
            digitouDireito = True
            qtdCols = qtdLins
    except ValueError:
        print ("Quantidades devem ser numeros naturais!\n")

lin = 1
while lin<=qtdLins:
    col = 1
    while col<=qtdCols:
        if col == 1 or col == qtdCols or lin == 1 or lin == qtdLins:
            print ("O", end="")
        else:
          print(" ", end="")
        col+=1 #col = col+1
    print()
    lin+=1 # lin = lin+1
    
print ("\nOBRIGADO POR USAR ESTE PROGRAMA!\n")
```

Comment: Fechou... nunca que eu faria isso ai sozinho rsrs. Obrigado pela ideia!